# How to conditionally display additional content in Flutter Dropdown Button based on dropdown state?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I am working on a Flutter application and have implemented a dropdown menu using DropdownButton. In this dropdown, I want to display the USA flag, the text "USA", and the country code "+1" when the dropdown is open, but only the USA flag when it's closed.

Currently, I have attempted to achieve this by customizing the DropdownButton and using conditional logic to display the additional content based on the dropdown state. However, I'm encountering issues with such implementation, once dropdown state is open, the content is only image, and updated only for the closed state.

Please see the code below:

```
// Widget block
class _CountryDropDownMenuWidgetState
    extends State<_CountryDropDownMenuWidget> {
  bool _isDropdownOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final viewModel = Provider.of<LogInEmailViewModel>(context);

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<int>(
          // isExpanded: true,
          value: viewModel.selectedIndex,
          onChanged: (index) {
            _isDropdownOpen = false;
            viewModel.selectItem(index!);
          },
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _isDropdownOpen = true;
            });
          },
          items: viewModel.dropdownItems.asMap().entries.map((entry) {
            final item = entry.value;
            return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
              value: entry.key,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(item.flagPath),
                  if (_isDropdownOpen)
                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  if (_isDropdownOpen)
                    Text(item.text),
                  if (_isDropdownOpen)
                    Text(item.countryCode),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
  // Viewmodel block
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<DropdownItem> dropdownItems = [
    DropdownItem(text: 'USA', flagPath: 'assets/images/logo2.png', countryCode: '+1'),
  ];

  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;

  void selectItem(int index) {
    _selectedIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  DropdownItem get selectedItem => dropdownItems[_selectedIndex];
```

[Image result on expended state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi1Gk.png)

My expectation was to have the additional content (USA text and country code) hidden when the dropdown is closed and displayed only when the dropdown is open. I am seeking guidance on how to correct this behavior and achieve the desired display based on the dropdown state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess on why your implementation could not be working is no setState in `onChanged`.

If that's to no avail please read below!

The better way to achieve your UI goals is to implement `selectedItemBuilder` property of `DropdownButton`.

By this,

You can provide separate widget for selectedItem( which is visible on closed state of button) and all options (which are visible in open state of button)

So put the flag in `selectedItemBuilder` and Row of flag,text and code in `items`.

Side note: this implementation is cleaner and more optimised.

[flutter doc with runnable example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html)

Comment: Thank you very much - I was not aware of the selectedItemBuilder method.